# liferay and database queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server, liferay, liferay-6

I need some guide.

I have a database(containing my table) and I want to use it in my liferay portlet. All I need to do with the database is to select a number of random data from it and delete the selected data. I do not need to create a database and relate my model to sql database or add any data to my DB.I know that liferay has a specific procedure to retrieve and store data(persistence layer and so on) and I know that liferay builder makes it easy to do all that.But liferay builder does some works that I must not use them. Is there another way(except liferay builder) to to make sql queries easily without getting engaged the details or If there is not can anybody give a guide(a link or sth) how to do database queries without any automation?

Comment: Are you looking for plain JDBC? While Liferay provides ServiceBuilder, it does not mandate you use any of it - you can use any other technique to get to the database.

Comment: JDBC could be an alternative. Actually I'm a bit confused with liferay model to deal with databases but I assume it would be better(in performance or security?!) to use it other than other techniques(correct me if I'm wrong!). Anything to help me go through it?

Comment: You can start here: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/service-builder

Comment: Sorry, I see now you can't use Service Builder for your application. I believe only ServiceBuilder is documented.

Comment: so you actually want to adopt an existing db with a liferay access mechanism? what about using service builder with your db ?

Comment: Yes! I want to use a mechanism for DB access like what liferay mechanism does(for example like what service builder does to access db). But as I mentioned above I do not want to(and can not) use Service Builder for my application.